# Why does the sizeof return a value when element is not set?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

int TEST_HB[10]; 
memset(TEST_HB,'9', sizeof( TEST_HB));

printf("%c\n",TEST_HB[9]);

printf ("TEST_HB[10]=%d\n",sizeof( TEST_HB[40]));   // shows 4
printf ("Arraysize=%d\n",(sizeof(int)*10));     // gets the expectected results
return 0;

}
```

I believe that sizeof (myArray) should return the total size of the array in bytes. But why does `sizeof( TEST_HB[40])` returns 4 when it is not defined ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TEST_HB[40]` is an expression with type `int` (and undefined behavior if evaluated, since `40` is too big for the array). So `sizeof(TEST_HB[40])` is the size of an `int` on your implementation: 4 is typical.

Importantly, `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand unless it's a VLA -- it just uses the type. Therefore your code has defined behavior even though there's no such object as `TEST_HB[40]`.

Actually, I say it has defined behavior, but `sizeof` evaluates to type `size_t`, which isn't printed with `%d`. Use `%zu` where available or consult your compiler documentation. You've got away with it here because you've got lucky with the varargs calling convention, plus either `size_t` is the same size as `int` in your implementation, or your implementation is little-endian, or both.

A fairly common use of the fact that `sizeof` does not evaluate the operand is to write something like this:

```
struct Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * number_of_foos_required);
```

`sizeof(*foo)` is the same as `sizeof(struct Foo)`, but to some people it's more "obviously" the right size to use. `foo` is uninitialized before the memory is allocated, so it's just as well that `sizeof` doesn't actually use the value of `foo`.

A less common use, that demonstrates the behavior of `sizeof`:

```
int i = 0;
printf("%d\n", i);
printf("%d\n", (int)(sizeof(i++))); // i++ is not executed
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Comment: +1 [future] well explained [ but I cant upvote until 1 have 15 reps ] :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof( TEST_HB)
```

is the size of the array (the size of `int[10]`)

```
sizeof(TEST_HB[40])
```

is the size of an element of the array (the size of `int`).

Note that the element `TEST_HB[40]` does not exist in your array (you array has only 10 elements), but as `sizeof` does not evaluate its operand, it is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof` operator yields the size of its operand. If you want to get the size of your array, you should use `sizeof TEST_HB` instead (no parentheses are needed).
`TEST_HB[40]` is indeed of type `int`, whereas `TEST_HB` is of type `int[10]`. Notice that, except with variable length arrays, the operand of the `sizeof` operator is not evaluated, so it does not lead to an undefined behavior.

> **C11 § 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**
>
> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.

Besides, use non-constant uppercase identifiers is considered as bad C programming style.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof( TEST_HB[40])` return the size of the int in the position 40 of your int array, hence the 4 bytes as size.